# HDFS NFS gateway "No groups available for user" warnings

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

I'm using the NFS gateway service to ingest some data into HDFS (CDH 5.4.5).

All seemed to be well until I received a message warning informing me that the logging directory free space was running very low. I had a quick look for big log files:

```
sudo find /var/log -type f -size +100000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
```

... and noticed a 34GB file called `/var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-cmf-hdfs-NAMENODE-[fqdn-of-name-node].log.out`. A quick peek inside showed that almost entirely consisted of this warning:

```
2015-11-30 13:41:15,535 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user [some_user]
```

Seeing this, I added the `some_user` user to the `hdfs` group, i.e. `usermod -a -G hdfs some_user` on the node running the NFS gateway, and then restarted the NFS gateway service. Unfortunately, the "No groups available for user ..." message is still getting logged at a ferocious rate.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? Does the `some_user` account need to be setup on each node, and not just the NFS gateway? Do I need to do something more than just restart the service for the changes to be effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user and its group need to be set up on the namenode. By default, Hadoop gets the group mappings from the OS settings there. See  for example here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#Group_Mapping

Comment: Thanks @Hellmar. That was it! I created the `someuser` account on the namenode.